# How to rebase last x commits on different branch?

Tags: git

I want to take the latest X commits from a branch and be able to apply them on top of different branch. For example doing `git rebase -i HEAD~10` would allow me to interactively modify and apply the last 10 commits on the same branch I'm on.

Is it possibly to do the same thing but apply the commits on a particularly other branch, where the history might have diverged a lot?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use the `--onto` flag.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10 --onto another_branch
```

Note that this will not create a new branch, nor will it move the actual changes to `another_branch`.

All changes will be applied to the same branch you are on.

So I suggest do it in several stages:

```
git checkout -b staging_branch
git rebase -i HEAD~10 --onto another_branch
git checkout another_branch
git merge staging_branch
```

Comment: The `-i HEAD~n` was exactly what I needed. I didn't know about that feature on git. I branched off from my `development` branch to realize my work was supposed to be a hotfix, thus branched off from `master`. Without `-i HEAD~n`, I was rebasing ALL `development` base onto `master`!!! Thanks.